# How to pass existing SqlTransaction and SqlConnection to an ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Ef4 (POCO). My application uses both traditional SQLConnection as well as EF4. In my application, i need to pass existing SqlTransaction and SqlConnection to the ObjectContext. How shall i do it.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ADO.net Entity Framework with an existing SqlConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518535/how-to-use-ado-net-entity-framework-with-an-existing-sqlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass your existing Sql Transaction into the ObjectContext, you need to either write the queries again in Entity Sql or LINQ to entities.