# Entity framework how to switch between database

Tags: entity-framework

In my project after completing development we are in mode of stabilizing the project. so we have come to a conclusion to introduce automation testing. Already we have one development database.By using that on Entity framework database first mode we have created edmx files and using it for database transaction. Now we have come up with another testing database with data needed for doing automation testing. I have no idea how to switch between these two database. because my project is tightly coupled with my development database.

Comment: if the schema of the two databases is the same, then you should only have to change the connection string.

Comment: if you need to do it in runtime, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841164/change-database-during-runtime-in-entity-framework-without-changing-the-connect. Otherwise, change the connection string in the app.config file