# How to "attach" an existing model to an existing DbConnection when creating an Entity Framework DbContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-connection, edmx

I have an assembly with an EDMX model. I can successfully create a `DbContext` specifying in the constructor a connection string with a reference to that assembly (`metadata=res://MyAssembly/MyModel.csdl|res://MyAssembly/MyModel.ssdl|res://MyAssembly/MyModel.msl ...`), and in that case everything works fine.

However, now I'm faced with a situation where I'm getting an existing `DbConnection` from an external source, as well as an existing `DbTransaction`. I'd like to have a strongly-typed Entity Framework view over this `DbConnection`. So, instead of using the connection-string `DbContext` constructor, I am using a different `DbContext` constructor that takes a `DbConnection` (and then using `context.Database.UseTransaction()` to set the existing transaction).

In this case, as soon as I try accessing one of my tables, I am getting an error, `The entity type MyType is not part of the model for the current context.` - it seems that my model isn't "attached" to the existing `DbConnection`.

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible to somehow "attach" a model from my EDMX-containing assembly to an existing `DbConnection`?
- I've noticed there's a `DbContext` constructor that takes both a `DbConnection` and a **`DbCompiledModel`**. This seems to be exactly what I need. How can I extract a `DbCompiledModel` from an existing EDMX-containing assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Just my luck, found an answer right after posting a bounty :) Almost the entire answer (minus the part about transactions) was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518535/how-to-use-ado-net-entity-framework-with-an-existing-sqlconnection) - I didn't think of searching for SqlConnection instead of DbConnection.

Essentially, given an `existingDbConnection` and an `existingDbTransaction`:

```
var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(
            new string[] { "res://*/" },
            new Assembly[] { Assembly.Load("My.Assembly.Name")});
            // can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() if in current assembly
var wrappedConnection = new EntityConnection(workspace, existingDbConnection, false);
var context = new DbContext(wrappedConnection, false)
context.Database.UseTransaction(existingDbTransaction);
```